# PI ACE NextEvent() is not read in (.vb)

Tags: vb.net, server

I am new to PI ACE Servers, but i wrote that code depending on a DataSet with Dates and Values (like "phase of X" and "Phase of Y").
The Problem is, that this code just reads in the first Date and the Phase before the Phase at t1.

I don´t see a mistake in the code so i hope you can help me out here:

```
Public Overrides Sub ACECalculations()

    Dim t1,t2 As Date
    t1= "13.05.2016 00:00"
    t2= "13.05.2016 05:00"

    Do
        t1 = TableStep.NextEvent(t1).LocalDate
        If TableStep.Value(t1) = "Phase X" Then
            Debug.Print(t1 & "" & "Phase X)
        Else 
            Debug.Print(t1 & "" & TableStep.Value(t1).ToString)
        End If
     Loop While t1<=t2

End Sub
```

Comment: Missing Quotation mark in `Debug.Print(t1 & "" & "Phase X)` Change to `Debug.Print(t1 & "" & "Phase X")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh you´re right and thx for your reply, but i fixed it myself by referring to `t1 and t2 as New PITimeServer.PITime` instead of `Date`.